# Specific problem with traversing an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, traversal

I have given the array:

```php
array(
   "firstName": null,
   "lastName": null,
   "category": [
        "name": null,
        "service": [
           "foo" => [
               "bar" => null
           ]
        ]
   ]
)
```

that needs to be transform into this:

```php
array(
    0 => "firstName",
    1 => "lastName",
    2 => "category",
    "category" => [
        0 => "name",
        1 => "service",
        "service" => [
             0 => "foo",
             "foo" => [
                  0 => "bar"
             ]
        ]
    ]
)
```

The loop should check if a value is an array and if so, it should add the key as a value (`0 => category`) to the root of array and then leave the key as it is (`category => ...`) and traverse the value again to build the tree as in example.

I am stuck with this and every time I try, I get wrong results. Is there someone who is array guru and knows how to simply do it?

The code so far:

```
private $array = [];
private function prepareFields(array $fields):array
{
    foreach($fields as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $this->array[] = $key;
            $this->array[$key] = $this->prepareFields($value);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->array[] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $this->array;
}
```

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: @KrisRoofe I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
function prepareFields(array $array): array
{
  return array_reduce(array_keys($array), function ($result, $key) use ($array) {
    $result[] = $key;
    if (is_array($array[$key])) {
      $result[$key] = prepareFields($array[$key]);
    }
    return $result;
  });
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/3BfKD**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this, check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/789d6604f6939873e4c529a1bce51dc76540444c)

```
    function array_format(&$array){
        $temp_array = [];
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
            $temp_array[] = $k;
            if(is_array($v)){
                array_format($v);
                $temp_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        $array = $temp_array;
    }
    array_format($array);
    print_r($array);
```